# how to warn about user quotas of ftp user in a /sbin/nologin shell?

Tags: bash, perl, ftp, quota

how would i do a check through a perl script or bash script remotely and throw a warning if the ftp upload size beyond the limits specified for that user.

only ftp login is allowed for the remote ftp server.

EDIT : I want the script to be invoked from the client PC/server, send a warning message to my  email stopping the upload, and  wait until there is enough space on the remote ftp server for that particular user.

Comment: Where would bash or perl get invoked on an ftp connection, though?

Comment: it should be invoked from the client server. i want it done remotely ..when the ftp file is getting uploaded.. suppose if i am uploading a 7 mb file for ftp user user1 and there is only 3 mb space left for that user...i should get a message stating not enough space on the device...please wait while the space gets cleared

Comment: one possible solutiion looks like http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/how-to-check-disk-usage-in-ftp